# React JS: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I created a brand new reactJS application via [these instructions](https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project), ran `npm i && npm run dev` and I get:

```
/home/www/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js:362
            showAll: args["--show-all"] ?? false,
                                         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.dev (/home/www/node_modules/next/dist/lib/commands.js:10:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/www/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next:141:28)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
```

Comment: What version of Node.js and npm do you use.

Comment: Node 12.22.9, NPM 8.5.1

Comment: My first guess: Node.js 12.22.9 doesn't support the operator `??`. It's outdated and should be updated.

Comment: Seems Ubuntu ships with this in their package manager by default (wtf?), updating fixed it.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Yeah, distro's update's are terrible for node.js,  You might find `nvm` better, https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm  The bonus is you can then flip between different versions etc.

Comment: @jabaa 22.04 this was

Answer (score 2):

You're using a version of Node.js that doesn't support this operator. Either replace this operator with equivalent code in your code base or update your Node.js version.

Answer (score 0):

[Nullish coalescing (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) is supported from Node.js `>= 14.x` consider updating your Node.js version, or use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) and `nvm use VERSION`.

Edit:

Next.js v13 dropped support for Node.js 12 and sets the minimum version to `14.6.0`(see [the release notes](https://nextjs.org/docs/upgrading#v13-summary))